# Continue processing when image cannot be loaded

Tags: python, imagick

In Python, I'm using [wand](http://docs.wand-py.org/) to get exif data (true date image created), and get image height and width to pass to a command line. That is all I'm using wand for. All works well except when the script encountered a image with bad data, which is bond to happen when processing 250,000+ images. When the file itself is corrupted, it causes the whole script to fail. I need to find a way to allow the script to continue executing even if the image cannot be properly loaded.

I'm using the following imports

```
import inspect, os, shutil, datetime, time, string, configparser, fnmatch,  os, MySQLdb, sys, ntpath, math
import MySQLdb.cursors as cursors
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display
from tendo import singleton
```

Here is the line that fails:

```
with Image(filename=file_original_path) as image:
```

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "process-files.py", line 244, in <module>
    main()
  File "process-files.py", line 216, in main
    with Image(filename=file_original_path) as image:
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 2744, in __init__
    self.read(filename=filename, resolution=resolution)
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/image.py", line 2822, in read
    self.raise_exception()
  File "/home/pc/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wand/resource.py", line 222, in raise_exception
    raise e
wand.exceptions.CoderError: Not a TIFF or MDI file, bad magic number 1280 (0x500). `assets/output/27/original.tif' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/566
Exception TypeError: TypeError("object of type 'NoneType' has no len()",) in <bound method Image.__del__ of <wand.image.Image: (empty)>> ignored
```

BTW a try except with a pass did not work either. Thank you.

Comment: 'Not a TIFF or MDI file': Do you have a TIFF as input?

Comment: Did you try catching both the `CoderError` and `TypeError` exceptions?

Comment: "BTW a try except with a pass did not work either." Please show us the code for that.

Comment: you may need to use extension `.tiff` instead of `.tif`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try/except works and will not cause the whole script failing.

```
import traceback
from wand.image import Image
from wand.display import display

def doSomething(f):
    _status = 'error'
    try:
        print "processing file: %s" % f
        with Image(filename=f) as image:
            print image
        _status = 'processed'
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
    finally:
        return _status

if __name__ == '__main__':
    result = {}
    images = ['/tmp/foo.png', '/tmp/bar.png', '/usr/share/locale/kde4/l10n/cf/flag.png']

    for i in images:
        status = doSomething(i)
        result[i] = status
    print result
```

Output: `{'/tmp/foo.png': 'error', '/usr/share/locale/kde4/l10n/cf/flag.png': 'processed', '/tmp/bar.png': 'error'}`

Answer (score 0):

Wrong... a try except pass did work. Confusing similar callback.